# SharePoint Server Object Model and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

I was trying to access an API which contains SharePoint Server Object Model codes from a project inside WCF server. My intention is to download a document which is on SharePoint server.

My codes are inside WCF server. SharePoint server is another server.

Whenever I try to access the server using

```
SPSite.Exists(new Uri(spServerURL))
```

It does not know the server. So when I change the WCF application pool to run under the Farm admin account, it works well.

Is it OK to do like that or it will be a security breach?

How should I try to access the document ?

Comment: Are both the servers in same domain.

Comment: Yes, in the same domain. But ours will be a internet portal. So I am afraid of security concern.

Comment: What you most probably want to do, is using Sharepoint *Client* Object Model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx - and dlls used by it, easily use in your WCF. Maybe it will be sufficient for You. If not, MAYBE it would be possible to extend SP Farm with server that hosts WCF, but do not use it as WFE or for any other application - it would be just used for your WCF access via SharePoint Object Model (it's just a guess, i never tried something like this).

Comment: Thanks Markek. But if I use client object model, I can't use things like impersonation. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better if you'll deploy your service to existing SharePoint web applications. So your service will work under SharePoint app pool account, so, you will not have problems with permissions of your service for SharePoint. Also it will be available for your SharePoint solutions from mapped path like this http:////_vti_bin/. This is useful, when you need to acces it from web contecxt you can use just relative path /_vti_bin/.

Check [this link](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html) for more information about service development for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: You mean "to host the WCF in the existing SharePoint server"?
I can't change the architecture of the design.

Comment: So, if you can't you need to run your service under appropriate account or do some kind of impersonation when you work with SharePoint object model.

Comment: I do the impersonation, but once I host WCF in another web server, I can't use SharePoint object model anymore since it's another web server.

Comment: If it is the same physical  server within sharepoint farm and your service call sharepoint object model under sharepoint app pool there shouldn't be problem.  I think it will be better if you'll run your service under the same account as your sharepoint application pool is running.  I don't see any problem with that